# Combobox with JPEG images

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, combobox

I've an old Visual C++ program where a Owner Draw Combobox is filled with bitmap images.
I need to rewrite the program making the combobox able to load jpeg or png instead of bitmaps.
I've read about the CImage class and so i've rewritten the code changing CBitmap to CImage

Loading phase:

```
...
    CImage image;
    image.Load(filepath);
    _ComboBoxBmp.AddImage(image,filename);
...
```

Loading function

```
void CComboBoxBmp::AddImage(CImage img, CString text)
{
    int nIndex = GetCount();
    CImage* image = new CImage;
    image->Attach(img.Detach());
    m_pBmpList.AddTail(image);

    int n = CComboBox::AddString(text);
    if (n != CB_ERR && n != CB_ERRSPACE)
    {
       int r = SetItemData(n, (DWORD)image);
       int Width = image->GetWidth();
       int Height = image->GetHeight();
       m_nItemWidth = 50*Width/100;
       m_nItemHeight = 50*Height/100;

       for (int i = -1; i < GetCount(); i++) 
          SetItemHeight(i, m_nItemHeight + 6);

    }
}
```

Drawing phase

```
void CComboBoxBmp::OutputBitmap(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS, bool selected)
{
    const CImage *image = (CImage*)GetItemDataPtr(lpDIS->itemID);
    if (image && image != (const CImage *)(0xffffffff)) 
    {
       CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDIS->hDC);
       CString string; 
       CPoint point;
       point.x = lpDIS->rcItem.left + 2;
       point.y = lpDIS->rcItem.top + ((lpDIS->rcItem.bottom - lpDIS->rcItem.top) / 2) - (m_nItemHeight / 2);
       DrawBitmap(image, pDC, point);
    }
}
```

The problems are in the last function:

```
void CComboBoxBmp::DrawBitmap(const CImage *image, CDC *pDC, const CPoint &point)
{
    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC((CDC*)pDC);

    BITMAP bm; 
    ((CBitmap*)bitmap)->GetBitmap(&bm);
    CBitmap *pBmp = memDC.SelectObject((CBitmap*)bitmap);
    pDC->StretchBlt(point.x, point.y, m_nItemWidth, m_nItemHeight, &memDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY );
    memDC.SelectObject(pBmp);

}
```

I don't know how to rewrite it because CDC::SelectObject accepts CBitmap but not CImages and all that i can obtain avter after several attempts is a dropdown list from the combobox with all blank images

Anyone can help to find a similar function SelectObject for the CImage class?

Comment: Did you miss [`CImage::StretchBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x180d9tc.aspx)?

Comment: Weel, actually i'm still using CDC::StretchBlt... I can make 1 an attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CBitmap::FromHandle` for conversion from `CImage` to `CBitmap`.
`CImage` class has an `operator HBITMAP()`, so it is available.

[CBitmap::FromHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/8ydch1a3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
CImage image;
// ...
CBitmap* pBitmap = CBitmap::FromHandle(image);
```

Comment: I had already made ​​this attempt but with no results.
After the paert:
    BITMAP bm; 
    ((CBitmap*)pBitmap)->GetBitmap(&bm);
I see that bm isn't correct because it havent correct values for width and height of the image

Comment: Your code is different with me. You didn't use normal conversion, because you are just converting using CBitmap*.

Comment: And what type of pBitmap? I can't find the type of that in your question code.